# Install fonts from within the code

Tags: fonts, xna

I'm currently using a custom font in my XNA game.
As you might imagine, the game wont start if the font isn't installed on the PC.
I'm planning on using try/catch to understand whether the font's installed or not.

Now, is there a way to install the font from within the code?
You can take in mind that the font file is in the Content folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is convert your font to a BMP spritefont, import the BMP image and change from "Texture" to "Sprite Font Texture" at the Content Processor in the properties.
You can see [Here](http://dudesknight.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/xna-custom-sprite-fonts/) how you can do this.