# XNA How can I install a font within my installer for my game

Tags: c#, fonts, xna, installation

I have a font that is required to play a game I am making in XNA. I have a setup project that installs the content and the primary output from my game. Is there a way I can make it so the font gets installed automatically through that same installer or do I need to make the user manually install it?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the font as a bmp file as described in the answer of this question linked below

[Install fonts from within the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045255/install-fonts-from-within-the-code)

Hope it helped you :)

Comment: Ok that makes sense :) How can I convert the font to a .bmp though? I don't really want to download a program to do it unless It's needed.

Comment: I think that every site with fonts has at least one image with every character from that font you want. Download that image using the "Save image.." option by right-clicking on the image and then use an online converter to convert that image to bmp